# How do I use knockout.js mapping to dynamically load modal box content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a modal box that I want to load data based on a selection on the main page. I figured that would be a good intro into using knockout.js which will be used in other aspects of the application later on. I am using Bootstrap modal for the modal.

Here is what I WANT to to:

1. Select which time sheet to process by pressing a button. Each time sheet has a different id.
2. Show more detail on that time sheet.
3. If there are problems with that time sheet, list the errors.
4. If there are no problems, give them the ability to sign it.

So I have my modal defined as :

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="signModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Sign time sheet</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div data-bind="foreach: summary">
        <p><span data-bind="text: HoursCodeDescription"></span>(<span data-bind="text: HoursCode"></span>) - <span data-bind="text: TotalHours"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success disabled">Sign time sheet</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Then I am pulling my summary of data by using [this article](http://softwaredevelopmentexperiences.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-build-grid-with-knockout-and.html)

```
<script>
    var id = 0;
    var viewModel;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Sign the timesheet
        $('.signTimesheet').click(function () {
            id = $(this).closest("div").find("h3.empId").attr("id");
            $('#signModal').modal('show');
            viewModel = SummaryViewModel();

        });
    });

    function SummaryViewModel() {
        var _this = {}

        _this.summary = ko.observableArray();
        ko.applyBindings(_this, $('.modal-body').get(0));

        function LoadSummary() {
            $.ajax({
                'beforeSend': function (xhrObj) {
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                },
                'async': false,
                'cache': false,
                'dataType': 'text json',
                'data': ({ "id": id }),
                'url': '/api/Timesheet/',
                'type': 'GET',
                'success': function (data) {
                    var results = ko.observableArray();
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.HoursSummary, {}, results);
                    for (var i = 0; i < results().length; i++) {
                        _this.summary.push(results()[i]);
                    };
                }
            });
        }

        LoadSummary();

        return _this;
    }
</script>
```

I am sure I am missing something with the approach I am taking, but I can't find any example that works similar to how I want it to operate. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I actually needed to do:

```
<script>
    var id = 0;
    var viewModel = {
        summary: ko.observableArray([{ HoursCodeDescription: "", HoursCode: "", TotalHours: 0 }])
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        // Sign the timesheet
        $('.signTimesheet').click(function () {
            id = $(this).closest("div").find("h3.empId").attr("id");
            $('#signModal').modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                'beforeSend': function (xhrObj) {
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                },
                'async': false,
                'cache': false,
                'dataType': 'text json',
                'data': ({ "id": id }),
                'url': '/api/Timesheet/',
                'type': 'GET',
                'success': function (data) {
                    viewModel.summary(data.HoursSummary);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Came across your example here and when trying to follow it my browser is returning `has no method "modal"`, I installed through nuget knockout modal and boostrap modal.